# Couldn't read the region / Failed to read Region from AWSConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, aws-mobilehub, amplify-ios

I have started AWSMobileClient and Amplify on my ios app, configured with awsconfiguration.json file. But the log showing like

- Couldn't read the region configuration from `awsconfiguration.json` / `Info.plist`. Please check your configuration file if you are loading the configuration through it.
- Couldn't read credentials provider configuration from `awsconfiguration.json` / `Info.plist`. Please check your configuration file if you are loading the configuration through it.

Comment: Did you added awsconfiguration.json file in your project.

Comment: Yes I have awsconfiguration.json

Comment: Issue fixed, I re-structured the awsconfiguration.json. now working good